# Accessing JSON data

Tags: json, jquery

If I am given the following data by a web-service:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "col1": "col 1 data 1",
            "col2": "col 2 data 1"
        },
        {
            "col1": "col 1 data 2",
            "col2": "col 1 data 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

how do I access the second col1?

As the following:

```
success: function( data ) {
         alert( data.d ) ;
},
```

gives me:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its an array with 2 elements containing `col1` and `col2`, so something like:

```
alert(data.d[1].col1);
```

(`0` is the first element, and then you choose "col1")

Answer (score 4):

```
success:function(data){
data = JSON.parse(data); // you will have to parse the data first
alert(data.d[0].col1);
```

Comment: when using the jQuery `$.ajax()` function with the `dataType` specified as JSON it'll automatically parse it.

Comment: Fair point, I just made the assumption it was already JSON as he could access the first level of the object :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
alert( data.d[1].col1 ) ;
```

In human:

1. start at data variable
2. go to d property.
3. d is an array, so look up the value at index 1 (second value)
4. look up the col1 property of that value.

May I suggest console.log? In Chrome and with Firefox/Firebug it will give you a nice log message which tells you more about your data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var json = {
    "d": [
        {
            "col1": "col 1 data 1",
            "col2": "col 2 data 1"
        },
        {
            "col1": "col 1 data 2",
            "col2": "col 1 data 2"
        }
    ]
};

alert(json.d[1].col1);
```

Specify the array index of `d` (starts with 0, so this would be 1) and then you can access child items. Here's a [working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ilmv/6SU89/).