# ajax JSON as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706374/accessing-json-data), you can access a JSON that has this format,

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "col1": "col 1 data 1",
            "col2": "col 2 data 1"
        },
        {
            "col1": "col 1 data 2",
            "col2": "col 1 data 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

and get data via 
`data.d[1].col1` (or col2, or other column names)

But what if I want to create a function and pass parameter to `jsonColumn`, an argument that will contian my desired column?
For example:

```
Function ajaxJSONgetter(JSONfile, htmlElement, **jsonColumn**)
$.ajax(JSONfile,
            {
                dataType: 'json', //this will always be thru jSON
                success: function (data, status, xhr) { 

                    swal(data.d[0].**jsonColumn**);

                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {

                }

            });
```

how do I pass "col1" to `jsonColumn`??

Comment: Try `data.d[0][jsonColumn]`.

Comment: @guest271314 the expected result is `col 1 data 1` sir.